# Why is Views "Query Execute Times" so high?

Tags: views, performance

I have a basic view that shows a list of members and their user points. The views query output show that this query takes over 1500ms to run.

Query build time    24.71 ms

Query execute time  1546.84 ms

View render time    88.29 ms

> SELECT users.picture AS users_picture, users.uid AS uid, users.name AS users_name, users.mail AS users_mail, users.created AS users_created, userpoints_total.points AS userpoints_total_points, 'user' AS field_data_field_motorcycle_user_entity_type, 'user' AS field_data_field_review_count_user_entity_type, 'user' AS field_data_field_address_user_entity_type
>
> FROM  {users} users LEFT JOIN {userpoints_total} userpoints_total ON
> users.uid = userpoints_total.uid WHERE (( (users.status <> '0') AND
> (users.uid NOT IN  ('1')) )) LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0

When I copy and paste that query into myphpadmin and run it there it takes less than 5ms. What else is happening in the "Execute Time"? I coudn't find any good help about that on the web.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When testing be sure to turn off the query cache  `SET SESSION query_cache_type = OFF`

Next step is to run `EXPLAIN` on the sql.

EXPLAIN SELECT users.picture AS users_picture, users.uid AS uid, users.name AS users_name, users.mail AS users_mail, users.created AS users_created, userpoints_total.points AS userpoints_total_points, 'user' AS field_data_field_motorcycle_user_entity_type, 'user' AS field_data_field_review_count_user_entity_type, 'user' AS field_data_field_address_user_entity_type

Comment: thanks! http://weevilgenius.net/2010/09/mysql-explain-reference had a good intro to EXPLAIN. Turns out that when I change the LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN it will run in ms rather seconds. Thanks again!!!